# incorrect constructor in Java child class

Tags: java, constructor

Can someone please help me understand why (in Java) class B is correct, while class C throws a compiling error?

```
class A {
    int x = 1;
    A(int x) { this.x = x; }
}

class B extends A {
    B() { super(2); }
    B(int x) { super.x = x; } //Error
}

class C extends A {
    C() { super.x = 2; }      //Error
    C(int x) { super.x = x; } //Error
}
```

Comment: Might be rather helpful if you told us the compiler error, no?

Comment: Implicit super constructor A() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the Constructor `C()` the Constructor `A()` is called - implicitly. You cannot prevent that, except by calling another constructor. But the constructor `A()` does not exist, just `A(int)`, thus error.  (The default constructor only exists implicitly if you didn't write ANY other constructor - as soon as you have another constructor, you must add the default constructor or it won't exist).